# android hidden webview, Is it possible?

Tags: android

I want to build an application which takes user/pass information from user and use it on an https webpage and extract the returned raw html code from that page.

I want to know is this possible?

If so, what sort of class i should use. Can it be done with some hidden webview mechanism. Sine i think we can access the java script variable in a webview from our application. So is this possible. Or i am just wasting my time in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if it is possible to 'download' a webpage without actually displaying it in a WebView then try this...

```
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(Url);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);
```

EDIT: Sorry - the Url parameter passed to HttpGet() above is actually a String variable containing a url to the wep page you want.

Comment: Hi, can i use it in the main activity or do i have to use a new thread for this to work in background??

Comment: You can use it in the main activity if it is expected to get the data you need quickly. If you think it may take some time then use an AsyncTask to handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old subject here, but I see that I'm not the only one facing this situation.

This is how I understand it:

HttpClient objects and WebView objects will not share the same "session" scope through your application.
That is, if you have this URL that performs authentication and starts a valid session on a website; and following that, you try to open one of those website pages - session protected - through the webview, the webview will act as if no session were available. WebView is not aware of the HttpClient session.

A solution to that is to call the URL that starts a session through the WebView.postUrl method like this:

`webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postParameters, "BASE64"));`

I'm sure this can be done in a hidden webView.