# Android webview and google acount?

Tags: android, webview

Hey everyone,
I'm working an app that includes a webbrowser inside.
I've done quite some progress with getting the webview widget to work as necessary, but this thing really puzzles me.

I can't get the webview to forget my google account, even with deleting cache and history, it still remembers it. Which is really annoying since the application will be used by many users on a single device.

Any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear cookies too.  Use [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) to remove all cookies.  For example, you can add this to your onDestroy():

```
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

Comment: thanks, this works like a charm. I added this piece of code to my onCreate method.
Had to use the SyncManager first:

        `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();`

Answer (score 1):

On top of clearing the cache and history locally, you could just loadUrl for:

> https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout

This should make sure the session is ended on Google's end.

Seems like a logical solution to me.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but still, wouldn't that be just a workaround, the users would have to wait for this page to load and stuff. what I'm trying to say is that I was hoping for a more elegant solution...

Comment: I don't really feel like it is a workaround -- during your logout just access the page behind the scenes.  Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294388/android-hidden-webview-is-it-possible